# creating bcp format file for sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert, bcp

I am stuck in creating bcp format file. My client is using MSSQL 2005 and I am remotely connecting through RDC. I am creating format file on the target client MSSQL Server using the following command,

> bcp myDatabase.TableName format nul -c -x -f someFile..xml -T

but the it prompt me with error

> An Error has occured while establishing a connection to the server.

---

My View pointing to a table having structure as under:

```
Colum Name          DataType
SKU                 Varchar(20)
ASIN                Varchar(20)
Price               Float
Quantity            Int
MarketplaceTitle    Varchar(50)
```

**Note: I have been through many similar questions but had no luck.**

Anyone can please provide me with a format file for the above View?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is actually connecting to your database, not the format file.

I've created a quick test:

```
-- DROP TABLE dbo.Test
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(
SKU                 Varchar(20),
[ASIN]              Varchar(20),
Price               Float,
Quantity            Int,
MarketplaceTitle    Varchar(50)
);
```

and here's a slightly more verbose syntax:

```
bcp YourDatabaseName.dbo.Test format nul -c -x -f c:\YourDir\format.xml -T -S YourServerName
```

so for me, this looks like this:

```
bcp sandbox.dbo.Test format nul -c -x -f c:\Test\format.xml -T -S "(local)"
```

Here's the file generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="SKU" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ASIN" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Price" xsi:type="SQLFLT8"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Quantity" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="MarketplaceTitle" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

HTH.

Comment: I have run bulk insert with your format file and did the job. Inserted all values in correct format but also prompt me with error "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 3 (Price)". How can we avoid this error?

Comment: That sounds like a data issue. Compare the schema in the source and target systems for consistency. Also, check your data to ensure ensure you don't have any unusual characters (i.e. terminators, carriage returns, tabs, etc.) in your variable-length columns.